# Why GraphQL is not designed as a valid json document?

Tags: json, facebook, graphql

I wonder why facebook invented a new markup for [GraphQL](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/05/01/graphql-introduction.html) instead of json.
Many rest api provide some query functionality like json-based query or json-rpc or simply using parameters.

I am not trying to debate, I am just curious to find the motive.

Comment: Don't they [explain that here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/05/01/graphql-introduction.html#why-invent-something-new)?

Comment: Not exactly, it justify very well to have a query language aside from rest api but not why they invent a markup that look like json instead of using json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the main reason is simplicity. You just list fields in the requested shape. With JSON, you'd need to write something like `: true`, to every line, need to use quotes property, commas, ...

Also, you need to describe arguments and fragments, which would require additional tweaking of the shape of the JSON.

With its own language, GraphQL can express itself more succinctly.

BTW this sort of question might be better asked on Quora rather than SO.